# OpenSSL 1.0.2.a and Centos5.7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, openssl

I have an old version of Centos (5.7) and I would like to enable TLS 1.2 due to Google Chrome warning about TLS 1.0

I tried to update with yum but I can see that no OpenSSL 1.x could be installed upon this version of Centos. So I've downloaded it manually, and installed under `/usr/local/openssl`

Next step: how can I "link" it to apache (I've got apache itk)?

## EDIT

Just to be more precise, I need to improve my Apache web server TLS protocol from 1.0 to 1.2 and, to do that, I need to update OpenSSL and to let Apache use it (but I don't know how. Have I to recompile apache? If so, how?)

New OpenSSL version is 1.0.2a

Comment: *"Installed it manually"* -> How? As in you compiled from source?  What is the exact path to the `.so` files?

Comment: @goldilocks: downloaded tar.gz, uncompress it, configured it to *not* override system one, `make` and `make install`.
This is how I've done

Comment: @goldilocks: I've written explicitly that my vesion is 1.0.2a O_O

Comment: Sheesh, sorry!  I'll delete that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> So I've downloaded it manually, and installed under /usr/local/openssl

After you do a `make install` for a library, you need to run `sudo ldconfig`; this lets the linker know about it.   Stuff in `/usr/local` should then take precedence unless you've changed the linker configuration.  Double check you have a `libssl` with an appropriate creation time in `/usr/local/lib`.

To then check if apache will use it, run `ldd` on the binary.

```
> which apache
/usr/bin/apache
> ldd /usr/bin/apache | grep ssl
```

The path after `libssl.so.10 =>` should be into `/usr/local`.  Note I just made up the name of the executable there, you'll have to figure that out.

---

If you *don't* want the new libssl used by anything but apache, **move it out of `/usr/local/lib`.**  Trying to avoid it ending up available there is more hassle than just moving it and prone to error and further confusion down the road.  So find those libraries (they will all have identical timestamps -- I think there's actually just two, `libssl` and `libcrypto`, with symlinks) and move them to, e.g., `/opt/openssl/lib`.  You can then start chrome with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openssl/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
myapache $@
```

You'll have to move or rename the real executable (e.g., note above `myapache`) and then put this script into `/usr/bin` as `apache`, or whatever the name of the real executable is.

Comment: will `sudo ldconfig` change my system openssl? Because I've read that I could be in trouble. BTW I've read elsewhere I need to recompile apache. PS.: I'm doing this upon a web server, I don't need to use chrome at all, but users upon my sites will

Comment: I've updated my question also

Comment: You don't have a choice about running `ldconfig` now.  **If you don't do it, it will happen at some later point.**  I've added a bunch of stuff in above about using a specific library with chrome.    As a further note, I think you are going to start running into trouble recompiling apache -- this will never end.  You should just upgrade the whole system if at all possible.

Comment: It's not a problem of chrome. I just wanted to update OpenSSL used by Apache but I don't want to update *system* OpenSSL. I've read that is possible but I don't know how

Comment: You can use the same strategy (starting apache with a script that exports `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) as I recommended for chrome.

Comment: I've download the latest version (again). I've also read that it's a big risk to use this version in a system-wide fashion with Centos 5.7. I can't understand if you're not understanding my question or if you disagree with this statement

Comment: I kind of did misunderstand it -- the problem is that chrome users of your site are getting this warning because of your apache (I took it to mean you want it upgraded because of chrome on your system >_<).  I'll edit this to refer to that instead, but the strategy as per my last comment would be the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will take a look if possible. I'm just wondering why some people recommend to recompile apache... Do you now?

Comment: I think on debian (?) systems there's a practice of statically compiling ssl into the server binary.   You should be able to tell that with the `ldd` check.  If it *doesn't* have a link to `libssl`, it was probably compiled in so you will have to remake it.   Perhaps `apache --version` or something similar will tell you this (I'm not much of an apache user).

Comment: ...You might also be able to check by finding your current libssl (on fedora 64-bit, it's `/usr/lib64/libssl.so`) and running `lsof` on it.  Apache should be there.